# ui-grid multiple on same page onRegisterApi

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to register a dynamic number ui-grid on same page so when I have only 1 on page I can user onRegisterApi function but if I have more than 1 how can I register the event on each ui-grid. So similar to onRegisterApi I have same problem on definition because every grid have custom definition.

I need to register the event because I want to connect/link event from page to 1 or more ui-grid in the page (es filter, change color, etc)

Comment: Have you got any solution? I am facing same problem

Comment: Yes. you need to declare an array on your page and store the api on this array. when you need to manipulate the ui-grid find it on the array. Pay attention to nested object.

Comment: thanks for the hint related to array. I ended up using data attribute of ui-router and added grids based on a particular state to it. Now it works like charm!!